# Why can't access my own file?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have a problem. I just purchased a new laptop and installed Visual Studio Community on to it. The code I've been writing is on a USB stick which is FAT32 and has been working on my old laptop fine (which is now out of action).

When I load VS it comes up with the Solution Explorer on the right but when I click on Form1.cs, for some reason, it tries to open it in Notepad and an error comes up saying Access Denied.

If I right click and select Open With..., select CSharp Editor (Default) it says "The Operation Could Not Be Completed"

I've registered my product as I thought that might be an issue but no matter what I try it won't open my project! The owner is set to Everyone but I cannot get the security tab to surface. The little gold padlock just wont go. I've downloaded Unlocker 1.9.2 but to no avail, it just says No Locking Handle Found. I cant copy or move the file. What can I do? Please help!

Comment: maybe encrypted USB drive?

Comment: how can I tell?

Comment: ask your question on superuser, here it's off-topic.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I disagree that this is off topic for SO. It is definitely programming-related since it has to do with opening a C# project in Visual Studio. The last I checked these are tools commonly used by programmers.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre On the other hand, the OP might get a better response on SU since the underlying problem is likely hardware and/or OS related.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice note that I attempted to reply. Okay, maybe not off-topic, but OP has better chance of an answer on superuser because it's basically a file access problem, nothing to do with C#

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Agreed.

Comment: ok will do that now.

Comment: @seanstylez just copy-paste your question there. It's fine like it is.